# Android Studio removes library classes from output app

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have disabled proguard in my project:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a [side menu](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/AndroidSideMenu) library. It's been addressed in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile files('libs/sidemenu.jar')
}
```

But when I compile and run my app, it complains that a class (`com.agimind.widget.SlideHolder$1` which was in the addressed library) is not found!

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{**.***.reader/**.***.reader.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.agimind.widget.SlideHolder
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1959)
        ...
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.agimind.widget.SlideHolder
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        ...
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
        at **.***.reader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:121)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        ...
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        ...
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
        at **.***.reader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:121)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        ...
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.agimind.widget.SlideHolder$1
        at com.agimind.widget.SlideHolder.<init>(SlideHolder.java:604)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        ...
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
        at **.***.reader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:121)
        at ...
```

**Note:** I tried `gradlew clean` too, with no success.

**Side note:** This project uses some big libraries and I have enabled `multi-dex` for that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was because I had not completed the steps necessary for `multi-dex`. I had left out adding this to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    ...
```

Because of that, the app was not able to locate classes in the second dex file.